# Intel AC 7265 Wireless card not detected

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, wifi-hardware-switch

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on to my HP Omen laptop. So far I love the system, but my wireless, audio and second monitor do not work. I have an Hp Omen with an Intel AC 7265 Wireless card.
Here is the results to

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

and the lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core 
Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) 
(rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 
04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake 
Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI 
Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point- 
H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point- 
H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H 
CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA 
Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root 
Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root 
Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root 
Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root 
Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller 
(rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 
31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 
31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
Mobile] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

edit:
I would like to add that I'm duel booting with Windows 10 and when using windows the Internet, audio, and second screen work fine

edit2:

```
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  17 
snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,
```

snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm

Comment: "Hard blocked: yes" Does switching the Airplane Mode button change this at all?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference. It seems to do nothing at all

Comment: Is the module `hp-wmi` loaded? Find out: `lsmod | grep wmi` If so, does it help to remove it? `sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi` Now does the switch work?

Comment: just added the out put of    `lsmod | grep wmi`

Comment: Is there any clue if you load the module? `sudo modprobe hp-wmi`? How about here? `dmesg | grep wmi`If there is no error, does the Airplane Mode button now work?

Comment: `sudo modprobe hp-wmi` returns `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hp_wmi': No such device`. `dmesg | grep wmi` gives no reply but the AP mode button still does not work

Comment: May I see all of: `lsmod` As the output will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TnXp6vNJ79/

Comment: Ideas anyone? I’ve had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a helper module is required to translate key presses into action. In your case, pressing the wireless button, sometimes known as Airplane Mode should be translated into, “turn on the wireless radio, Mr. Kernel.” There is usually a wmi or laptop or wireless module to do so. Examples are hp-wmi, thinkpad_acpi, acer_wmi and many more.

We tried to load *hp-wmi*, the most likely candidate, and the result was that the module doesn’t work for your Omen.

Next, in your lsmod; that is, the list of all loaded modules, we see nothing whatever that is helpful to help.

Next, when we search Google for Linux on the HP Omen, we see a few examples where *removing* a loaded module, namely acer_wmi, causes the button to work. Here are some examples:

http://martinsosic.com/linux/2015/03/01/arch-linux-on-hp-omen.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316062/hp-omen-linux-mint-wifi-not-working

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337582

However, the module acer_wmi isn’t loaded here at all, so it is obviously ineffective to try to unload a module that isn’t loaded at all.

I have three suggestions. First, file a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/

Second, buy, with a generous return period, or borrow a known working USB wireless and see if it works. Here at my post #22, are some suggestions: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573

Finally, you might have success by taping off pin 20 on the wireless card: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150597

http://www.jarzebski.pl/files/images/mask-pin-20-2.jpg

I am sorry that, at the current time, there are no better solutions.