# Wifi adapter not found (wireless lan hard blocked) on Ubuntu 18.04 dual-boot Windows on Hp pavilion power

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 18.04, hp

**Background**

I have a new HP (pavilion power) laptop 15-CB040ND with originally windows 10 home on it. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows for dual-boot, although I should mention that the instal first froze and had to add the line acpi=off in GRUB to get to the install screen and run ubuntu.

After installing I noticed I had no wifi, upon going to wifi settings it states that no wifi-adapter can be found. I searched and triedy many solutions on internet, but it did not help. The first thing I tried was to reinstall the wifi with the command:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

but this did not work.

As a side note, **I do have wifi while booting into windows** and only have internet on ubuntu through USB tethering.

**Searching for solution**

Upon searching the internet I came across the command:

> rfkill list all

Which gave

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  

   Soft blocked: no

   Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN   

   Soft blocked: no     

   Hard blocked: yes
```

So my wireless Lan is hard blocked and sudo rfkill unblock all does not help. Some people say this can unlocked with a wifi signal button, but I do not have this. I do have airplane mode, but it does not do anything and besides, **my wifi is working in windows.**
And some other like [Wifi doesnt work on fresh ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04) and [Why is Wifi not working on my HP laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168909/why-is-wifi-not-working-on-my-hp-laptop) say that some things can be blacklisted and this unlocked the hard block and enabled wifi for them.

My question is how I can fix my wifi? I have not properly tried blacklisting as I do not know what to blacklist for my laptop. From another link I cannot find anymore I tried the following commands which it worked for another person:

> sudo modprobe -r hp-wireless

But did not unlock it and I tried:

> sudo modprobe hp-wmi

But this said I do not have such a device

Below I have executed some commands to give info about my laptop and hopefully can be of use to help me fix my wifi:

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
```

> lsmod | grep -e hp -e wmi

```
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
```

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

> uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl

```
  HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    3.769394] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't find IRQ for PCI INT A; please try using pci=biosirq
[    3.825211] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.903684] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    3.910727] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    3.940168] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: b8:08:cf:a6:2e:67
[    3.978811] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.618745] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: I wish I had a working solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050821/intel-ac-7265-wireless-card-not-detected/1051520#1051520 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ahh that is kinda annoying. Does this only occur with ubuntu 18.04? What if reinstall it on ubuntu 16.04? Would that resolve it? Or another solution that is mentioned in there is to buy a USB wireless that may work in ubuntu? And would the same problem occur in Ubuntu if I used a virtual machine for it instead of installing?

Comment: It is *very* annoying. It has existed in several versions of Ubuntu; however, it doesn't take much to download and try Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, for example, and click the "Try Ubuntu" option to check the operation of the Airplane Mode button. I will be very surprised if it works as the helper modules hp-wireless and hp-wmi are the same or older than that in 18.04. USB wireless may well work. As I said in the thread I linked, try it within a return period in case it doesn't. Even better, borrow a USB wireless from a friend. It is regrettable as HP make very nice laptops.

Comment: @chili555 I tried an older version of Ubuntu that I used for my desktop a year ago: ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 iso file and picked the "Try Ubuntu Without installing" option and my wifi worked automatically! I also did not have any problem befhorehand to adjust acpi=off. Now I have fully installed ubuntu 16.04 and my wifi is working, also shutting down does not freeze/hang as it was the case in Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions, it gave insight to my problem and was happy someone tried to respond to my question, so again thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome Glad it's working and glad you reported back. I'm certain it will help some others who find this with a Google search.